Difficulty Finding Transition State for Singlet Oxygen Reaction with 1,3-Diphenylisobenzofuran (DPBF) Using QST2 in Gaussian
I'm currently trying to model the interaction between singlet oxygen (1O2) and 1,3 diphenylisobenzofuran (DPBF) using Gaussian 16 program package. The goal is to find the transition state (TS) for this reaction so that I can determine the intrinsic reaction coordinate (IRC) and understand the reaction pathway in both forward and reverse directions.
However, I've encountered difficulties in setting up the calculation. I have the optimized structures of the product (the endoperoxide formed from DPBF and 1O2) and the separate geometries of singlet oxygen and DPBF. The problem arises when I attempt to use the QST2 method. I can't find a suitable way to position the singlet oxygen relative to DPBF in the reactant complex to ensure a valid starting geometry for the calculation. Without a proper initial guess, the QST2 method fails, and I'm unable to proceed with QST3 or direct TS optimization using Opt=(TS, CalcFC).
I'm looking for advice on how to correctly orient and place the singlet oxygen molecule relative to DPBF to facilitate a successful QST2 calculation. Additionally, are there alternative methods or strategies to determine the transition state for this type of reaction? Would generating an intermediate structure for use with QST3 be a better approach? Any tips or best practices for finding transition states in reactions involving singlet oxygen would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!
Here is one of the Gaussian inputs I've been using:
#p b3lyp/6-311+g(d,p) Opt=(QST2,CalcFC,NoEigenTest) freq scf=verytight int=(grid=ultrafine,acc2e=12)

Reactant

0 1
 C                  1.05422500    0.07723800    0.26483000
 O                 -0.03358700   -0.57687300   -0.34290500
 C                 -1.08335400    0.12961000    0.29789100
 C                 -0.67997300    1.58745400    0.08145700
 C                  0.72394600    1.55773900    0.05125300
 C                  2.33234100   -0.60356800   -0.05619500
 C                  2.57484354   -1.23904909   -1.27373461
 C                  3.31066904   -0.63876205    0.94661440
 C                  3.80473616   -1.85528553   -1.51114515
 H                  1.80873622   -1.25419768   -2.03768705
 C                  4.53619468   -1.25234767    0.70772625
 H                  3.13574415   -0.23448708    1.93588717
 C                  4.78936279   -1.85073283   -0.53018624
 H                  3.99232288   -2.33424114   -2.46509740
 H                  5.28690114   -1.28280228    1.48855882
 H                  5.74655657   -2.32459350   -0.71796580
 C                 -2.37145500   -0.54702600   -0.01531000
 C                 -2.59218191   -1.24804921   -1.19931799
 C                 -3.36589880   -0.55563578    0.98943280
 C                 -3.80310234   -1.91146431   -1.40502316
 H                 -1.82201177   -1.28095167   -1.95961835
 C                 -4.56995765   -1.21728490    0.77807365
 H                 -3.22638779   -0.07794426    1.94674037
 C                 -4.79114774   -1.89004744   -0.42800212
 H                 -3.97342361   -2.44578950   -2.33233951
 H                 -5.32896982   -1.22575152    1.55087659
 H                 -5.73091870   -2.40406339   -0.59750709
 C                  1.46002100    2.72774100   -0.00254400
 C                 -1.37516300    2.78451800    0.03866000
 C                 -0.63279600    3.96520000   -0.06452900
 H                 -1.15277100    4.91477100   -0.11990000
 C                  0.76190200    3.93808700   -0.08300200
 H                  1.31688400    4.86662600   -0.15185500
 H                  2.54193100    2.72726200    0.02700500
 H                 -2.45545500    2.82512700    0.09836300
 O                 -0.68791966    0.75028192    1.94057114
 O                  0.71049782    0.74231618    1.91997992

Product

0 1
 C                  1.06483600   -0.10665600    0.33277700
 O                  0.00000300   -0.76315900   -0.36160100
 C                 -1.06483000   -0.10666300    0.33277500
 C                 -0.69869300    1.36002000    0.16159400
 C                  0.69868900    1.36002600    0.16159600
 C                  2.42678400   -0.61982000   -0.02204500
 C                  2.99410000   -0.24161100   -1.24294600
 C                  3.12295200   -1.48141700    0.82851400
 C                  4.24652800   -0.72480000   -1.61110000
 H                  2.45102000    0.42050200   -1.90722500
 C                  4.38098900   -1.95439900    0.46001000
 H                  2.67793700   -1.77858300    1.76881300
 C                  4.94400400   -1.57943100   -0.75794200
 H                  4.67717000   -0.43430600   -2.56258300
 H                  4.91885500   -2.62032300    1.12514600
 H                  5.92143100   -1.95218200   -1.04294800
 C                 -2.42677800   -0.61982800   -0.02204500
 C                 -2.99409500   -0.24161800   -1.24294500
 C                 -3.12294700   -1.48142500    0.82851300
 C                 -4.24652500   -0.72480400   -1.61109900
 H                 -2.45101400    0.42049400   -1.90722400
 C                 -4.38098500   -1.95440500    0.46001000
 H                 -2.67793500   -1.77859400    1.76881300
 C                 -4.94400100   -1.57943400   -0.75794100
 H                 -4.67716600   -0.43430800   -2.56258200
 H                 -4.91885200   -2.62032800    1.12514600
 H                 -5.92142900   -1.95218400   -1.04294600
 C                  1.41981600    2.53979800    0.13544800
 C                 -1.41982800    2.53978700    0.13544400
 C                 -0.69772100    3.73888300    0.06743100
 H                 -1.23108000    4.68136500    0.01690000
 C                  0.69770000    3.73888800    0.06743300
 H                  1.23105100    4.68137400    0.01690400
 H                  2.50334200    2.54382400    0.16013100
 H                 -2.50335400    2.54380500    0.16012300
 O                 -0.73382600   -0.42386600    1.72221400
 O                  0.73382900   -0.42386200    1.72221700






Probably not too much help, but still: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86495/4945  I really thought I had written something on TS searches. Have you modeled the dissociated products as a supermolecule? Have you tried searching [mattermodeling.se]? (Also I found what I wrote, but that comes after… https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/87/49) You might want to try something with Nufged Elastic Band approach to TS search.
